# Restore .sql.xz file to postgresql database in docker

Tags: database, postgresql, docker

First, I follow the postgresql instruction on docker:

`docker run --name test-postgres`

then i tried to restore my db by the following command:

`xz -dc matrix-ww.sql.xz | docker exec -i test-postgres psql -U postgres matrix --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on --single-transaction`

the command seems executed. however, when i check the database and its tables, the database is still empty.